# get 2 or more column values in a jqgrid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way to get the first column value and the second column value in a jqgrid row? 
I am using this code to get the first value of the row in my other program,

`$("#tblTallySheet").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')`

This is to delete a data in my table:

```
function tallyDelData(){
  var selected = $("#tblTallySheet").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');  
  var datas = {
    "SessionID": $.cookie("SessionID"),
    "operation": "delete",
    "keyFields": [{"name":"tallyDate", "value":selected}]
  };
  tallyUpdate(datas);
} 

function tallyUpdate(dat){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'processjson.php?' + $.param({path:'tally/update',json:JSON.stringify(dat)}),
    dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
    success: function(data) {
      if ('error' in data)
      {
        showMessage('ERROR: ' + data["error"]["msg"]);
      }
      else{
        $('#tblTallySheet').trigger('reloadGrid'); 
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Since my first column is date and that there are datas that have the same date, I'd like to know if the function would only affect on the selected row (note: there are several rows that have the same date)?

If selecting the date row is not good, I want to get the second values which is a plank number (since my program cannot have two same plank number in same date). But how can I do it?

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to get the cell contain identified by the column name of the column index. To get contain of all column of the row you can use [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method.

The method `$('#tblTallySheet').trigger('reloadGrid')` which you use in the code reload the full grid and not the selected row. If you need update only one row you can use `setRowData`.

Currently you send to the server only the id of selected row without any data. Is it what you want or you want include in the `datas` object more information? I recommend you additionally use `cache:false` parameter of the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to be sure that you really end something to the server and not use the previous server response from the cache. Currently in the Internet Explorer you can has the problem.

To give you more advices one have to see the context where the function which you posted are used.